# Getting my bubble sort to work with a double linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I've been trying to get bubble sort a double link list, and i read on the internet to get it working with a single linked list would be easier, so i tried that and this is my code

```
public void bubbleSort()
    {
        StudentNode n;
        boolean isSorted=false;

        for(int i=lenght-1; i>1 && isSorted==false; i--)
        {            
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                n=L.head;
                isSorted=true;
                for(int k=0; k n.next.data)
                {
                    isSorted=false;
                    swap(n, n.next);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void swap(StudentNode N1, StudentNode N2)
    {
        int temp=N1.data;
        N1.data=N2.data;
        N2.data=temp;

    }
```

How would i change it to work with a double linked list?

Comment: Is this homework? Because I would suggest using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: Yeah it is, how would i go about implementing Collections.sort on a double linked list, as i haven't made a list like // DoubleLinkedList<String> list = new DoubleLinkedList<String>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your implementation point of view, it really doesn't matter whether it's doubly linked list or not, for the sorting(bubbling) part at least as you are simply changing the content instead of pointers.

Comment: You were right, if i was to have two list, how would i change ".data" to be different type of data?

Comment: In that case, you would be changing pointers instead of data. The code for that is little bit complicated than what you have but you could modify you swap function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only change the content (data) of each node, and don't move the nodes themselves, I don't see any reason to change anything.